# using dynamic linq to filter a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have two class like this

```
public class Error{
   public string Code{get;set;}
   public string Description{get;set;}
}

public class Row{
   public List<Error> Errors {get;set;}
   ....
}
```

So, for each row, can exists more errors.
It's possible using dynamic linq select the row that have an error code(for example Code1)?

So, if the row contains Code1 and Code2, i want select the row.

if in the example below query has a list of rows i want a query like this

```
query.Where("Errors != null && Errors.Code.contains('Code1')")
```

Comment: What really is *dynamic* in your query?

Comment: the example isn't dynamic, i have a table where the user can select from a list of code

Comment: Then why the requirement for `dynamic-linq` which is associated with System.Linq.Dynamic package for string based `Select`, `Where`, `OrderBy` etc. queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's possible using dynamic linq select the row that have an error code(for example Code1)?

The way I understand it, you have something like this

```
IQueryable<Row> query = ...;
string code = "Code1";
```

and you want the Dynamic LINQ equivalent of the following static query:

```
var result = query
   .Where(row => row.Errors != null && row.Errors.Any(error => error.Code == code));
```

Since in Dynamic LINQ every `Enumerable` extension method lambda enters a separate "scope", the members inside are accessible through special `it` identifier or no identifier at all. Also it allows you to pass parameters and refer to them inside the query string by index using `@p0`, `@p1` etc.

Hence the equivalent Dynamic LINQ query of the above could be like this:

```
var result = query
    .Where("Errors != null && Errors.Any(Code == @0)", code);
```

If instead of exact match you want `string.Contains`, simply replace `Code == @0` with `Code.Contains(@p0)`.

Of course you could embed the string literal value inside, but keep it mind it requires to be surrounded with double quotation marks (`"`):

```
var result = query
    .Where("Errors != null && Errors.Any(Code == \"Code1\")");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var codes=new List<string>{"Code1","Code2"}; 
// given a list of codes you want those rows that contains all codes
var result= rows.Where(r=> codes.All(c=>r.Errors.Any(e=>e.Code==c)));
```

To avoid the null checking of the error list, I suggest you initialize the list in an empty constructor:

```
public Row()
{
   Errors=new List<Error>();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i want use Dynamic linq, not linq.

Comment: @user3401335 Why are you more concerned about the tool used, than the outcome?

Comment: because i have twenty filters in the table(jqgrid), so i want use dynamic linq to query the table without write condition in the code

Answer (score 1):

What you really want to do is to use something like the PredicateBuilder:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
IQueryable<Error> SearchProducts(Row row, string[] codes, string[] keywords)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Error>();

    foreach (string code  in codes)
    {
        string temp = code;
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Code.Contains(temp));
    }
    foreach (string keyword in keywords)
    {
        string temp = keyword;
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Description.Contains(temp));
    }
    return row.Errors.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the where extension method of linq. and check if the code is equals to  Code1 or Code2 and convert the result into list of Error

```
 List<Error> rows = row.Errors
            .Where(x => x.Code == "Code1" && x.Code == "Code2")
            .ToList();
```

OR

```
var result = (from x in row.Errors
            where x.Code == "Code1" && x.Code == "Code2"
            select x).ToList();
```

Comment: It's an and (&&) and I think the OP doesn't want to do that hardcoding, and it wasn't me who downvote, I don't like to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Row> rowCollection = ...; //your rows
var result = rowCollection
    .Where(r => r.Code.Contains("Code1") && r.Code.Contains("Code2"))
    .ToList();
```